# Is there any chance to find source of javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm working in a large project that was developed for several years and had tons of code. Recently uninformative alert start to appear. It just says Undefined. I need to find the source of this alert. Is the any chance to make something like "breakpoint on alert"? I want to see the source of this alert.
One possibility is to redefine alert function. I tried to make it in firefox without any success.

Comment: you are on which system ?? Linux or Windows or ??

Comment: Have you tried searching all alerts in your project? There should not be too mane of them

Comment: `window.alert = console.trace` should do it, yes.

Comment: Vsevolod Goloviznin, I tried and no one breakpoint fired

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd go with redefining window.alert right at the start of the code for this type of development purposes.

```
window.alert = function(e){ console.warn( "Alerted: " + e ); }
```

This will give You a line number for sure. ( Tested on chrome console )

Comment: For some reason breakpoint in firebug didn't stop on console.warn( "Alerted: " e); but it work perfectly in Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is this is the reason, but on a React-TypeScript stack this wasn't providing the line number in my Chrome console. However, I was able to get more information by destructuring `e` like this: `console.warn("Alerted: " + { e });`. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but thought I would help out with a simpler solution.  A very easy way in Chrome to find the source is by placing a debug in the console on window.alert:

```
debug(window.alert)
```

This will break on alert and take you to the source.  In general, using console with debug(fname) will break whenever the function fname is called.

Comment: Thank you - this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I get `debug is not a function` when I paste that into the console

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation to Vsevolod's method, in FireBug over Firefox for example, you could place one conditional breakpoint on each and every alert(), and see which one fires off, then go up the callstack shown by FireBug.
The condition could be "typeof whatever_variable_is_displayed == 'undefined'".